# How to trigger a jQuery click event on an anchor element with an <object> child?

Tags: jquery, object, svg, click, jquery-events

I try to trigger a click event if someone clicks on a an `<a>`nchor that has an `<object>` child:

```
$(function() {
    $("object").click(function() {
        alert("test");
        return false;
    });
});
```

The markup:

```
 <a>
   <object data="menu-item-2.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
 </a>
```

I would expect that clicking on an `<a>` would trigger a click-event. It doesn't. Still, It would work with a mouseenter event.

How do I make it trigger a click event?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LyLGp/1/)**

You were missing href in the anchor tag,

Change in html

```
<a href="#">aa
   <object data="menu-item-2.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</a>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
  $('a').each(function (){

  if($(this).children('object').length > 0)    
     $(this).click(function() {
         alert("test");
         return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: I have updated my answer and gave link for live demo, I hope its what you need

Comment: Adil, I'm wondering why You used each? I think that maybe better would be for example add class to anchor and simply attach click event to that class. Can You write pros of Your solution?

Comment: In OP the event is required to bind with anchor which have object as children and some time molding the html for solution is not desirable as suggested by adding class. Event is attached to element not class as you suggested. Event are attached to elements having particular class and behind the scenes event is attached to all elements iteratively as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for answer. After Your explanation I did a little research and inter alia I found interesting article about improving jQuery code: http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx

Comment: @Adil: I should have been more specific. I try to make the whole `<a>` block hoverable, including the space taken up by `<object>`.

Comment: @Mathias what about adding display: block to a in CSS?

Comment: Event is binded to a and object between a will be clickable try and tell me if any problem